# Is ARM toolchain's gcc regular c or embedded c?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, embedded

I'm unsure which I'm using. I look it up and some answers say that it's the the host machine that determines if c is embedded c or not, so like, pc -> c, mcu -> embedded c.

edit: I use arm-none-eabi-xxx

Comment: C is C, no matter the target. What do you mean when you say "embedded C"?

Comment: Also, which ARM toolchain are you talking about? There are many different versions, made by different vendors.

Comment: an mcu is not automatically embedded, likewise a pc can run "embedded" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

arm-none-eabi-gcc is a cross-compiler for bare-metal ARM.  ARM is the *target*, the *host* is the machine you run the compiler on - the development host.

In most cases you would use such a compiler for developing for bare-metal (i.e. no fully featured OS) embedded systems, but equally you could be using it to develop bootstrap code for a desktop system, or developing an operating system (though less likely).

In any event, it is not the compiler that determines if the system is embedded.  An embedded system is simply a system running software that is not a general-purpose computer.  For example many network routers run on embedded Linux such as OpenWRT and in that case you might use arm-linux-eabi-gcc.  What distinguishes it is that it is still a cross-compiler; the host on which you build the code, is not the same machine  architecture or OS as that which will run it.

Neither does being a cross-compiler make it "embedded" - it is entirely possible to cross compile Linux executables on Windows or vice versa with neither target being embedded.

The point is, there is no "Embedded C" language, it is all "Regular C".  What makes it embedded is the intended *target*.  So don't get hung-up on classification of the toolchain.  If you are using it to generate code for embedded systems it is embedded, simple as that.  Many years ago I worked on a project that used Microsoft C V6 (normally for MS-DOS) in an embedded system with code on ROM and running VRTX RTOS.  Microsoft C was by no definition an embedded systems compiler; the "magic" was done by replacing Microsoft's linker to "retarget" it to produce ROM images rather than a .exe.

There are of course some targets that are invariably "embedded", such as 8051, and a cross-compiler for such a target could be said to be exclusively "embedded" I guess, but it is a distinction that serves little purpose.

Comment: embedded is one of those, I dont even know what to call it words.  it is heavily based on context, it has a very wide definition, some individual groups or companies have a specific definition that varies from other groups or companies.   There is a list of problem words like that in the software world.  And I am fascinated that so many people get hung up on these terms and assume there is a fixed definition.  assume there is not a fixed definition.   for that matter with does C language mean.  how many individual, incompatible specs have their been?  not to count the implementation defined

Comment: @old_timer : You of course know an embedded system when you see one!  When I say  "_not a general-purpose computer._", the term "_general-purpose computer_" needs qualification.  _A processing platform on which the end-user can load and run arbitrary executables developed by third-parties and unknown to the platform developer_ is  what I mean, so that includes smartphones, tablets etc.  If you are developing the system-software for such a platform that could be considered embedded, but developing an app for such a platform is not embedded dev (in my definition).

Comment: .. there is still ambiguity of course.  For example Raspberry Pi might be embedded in a system or used as a general purpose computer, and there are plenty of examples of embedded PCs - running Windows, Linux or an RTOS.  So it is not the platform that determines whether it is general purpose or embedded, but rather the _system_ itself.  To that end the description at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/embedded is wholly inadequate (in all its incarnations), but "improving" it is a minefield I have chosen not to enter ;-)

Comment: [tag:embedded] has more meaning than [tag:iot], because you take the first ambiguity and add more.  There are many OSs that can be embedded, just like an embedded system can be constructed with an allocator (and hence you may want `malloc()` and `free()` for portability).  Others require no allocators for safety, etc.  As system capabilities expand and markets expect more, the embedded term has expanded scope over time.  Also vendors add functionality like AMP; where you have both real-time and high-performance CPUs in one package; where a system may be both.

Comment: Sorry @artlessnoise that seems a bit non-sequiteur.  Which of the previous points are you commenting on?  Where did IOT come in?  It is true that there is a wide spectrum of embedded systems.  I think my simple definition covers them all?

Comment: The point that embedded is ill-defined.  Ie. ambiguity.  My point is that the rapid change of technology is a major contributor to this and not matter what the answer is today, it will be different in the future.

Comment: @artlessnoise  I disagree (I think - we may in fact be in _violent agreement_) - it is rather that _narrow definitions_ are inadequate and the breadth of embedded system means that "_embedded systems developer_" _is_ ambiguous - what constitutes an embedded system remains constant given a sufficiently broad and accurate definition - which I think I have given.  This is not really the place for this discussion, but I see no counter examples that defy my definition.

Answer (score 1):

There are many versions of arm gcc toolchains. The established naming convention for cross compilers is,

- arm-linux-xxx - this is a 'Regular C', where the library is supported by the Linux OS.  The 'xxx' is an ABI format.
- arm-none-xxx - this is the 'embedded C'.  The 'xxx' again indicates an ABI.  It is generally 'newlib' based.  Newlib can be hosted by an RTOS and then it will be almost 'Regular C'.  If it is 'baremetal' and the newlib features are defaulted to error this is most likely termed 'embedded C'.

Embedded 'C++' was a term that was common sometime ago, but has generally been abandoned as a technology.  As stated, the compiler itself is independant.  However, the library/OS is typically what defines the 'spirit' of what you asked.

---

The ABI can be something like 'gnueabhf' for hard floating point, etc.  It is a calling convention between routines and often depends on whether there is an FPU on the system or not.   It may also depend on ISA, PIC, etc.

Comment: As far as compiling C to asm/object, the arm-linux-xxx and arm-none-xxx both work the same.  When you get into library/system calls is where it will start to vary.  If you are generating bare metal code for an mcu without using libraries, then either work fine/equally.

Comment: From what I'm reading, it seems like embedded c is just c with different libraries used, where the libraries are built to work with the constraints of an embedded chip? Like, not all of Linux OS stuff fits on a chip and so modified libraries have to be used.

Comment: @old_timer  That is mainly true; but you need to use '-ffreestanding' with the Linux verison.  libgcc.a is fine, but libm.a and libc.a can end up making syscalls in places. gcc will include 'libc.a' and 'libm.a' by default (at least for some options).  You absolutely can use 'arm-linux-xxx' for bare metal; Just you need to be more careful.  Afair, you might even need to make sure not to call libgcc.a in some instances.

Comment: yes if you use gcc to link.  but then you run into those problems I use gcc to compile and ld to link, so fair enough, i did not elaborate past going from C to asm/obj...with the linker some of those freestanding and others are not necessarily needed, I have gone without them many times with no problem.  But for my more formal makefiles I put them in there.

Comment: yes libgcc can/has system specific say divide by zero handlers and such that can vary by gcc build type.

Answer (score 0):

The C language allows two different flavours of targets: *hosted* and *freestanding*. Hosted means programs running on top of a OS like Windows or Linux, freestanding meaning everything else. Examples of freestanding systems are "bare metal" microcontrollers, RTOS on microcontrollers, the hosted OS itself.

There are just a few minor differences between hosted and freestanding:

- The standard library

  - Hosted compilers must support all mandatory parts of the C standard library.
  - Freestanding compilers only need to implement `<float.h>, <iso646.h>, <limits.h>, <stdalign.h>, <stdarg.h>, <stdbool.h>, <stddef.h>, <stdint.h>` and `<stdnoreturn.h>`. All other standard headers are optional.
- Valid forms of `main()`

  - Hosted compilers must support `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Other implementation-defined forms of main() need not be supported.
  - Freestanding compilers always use an implementation-defined form of main(), since there is nobody to `return` to. The most common form is `void main (void)`.

"Embedded C" just means C for embedded systems. It's not a formal term. (For example not to be confused with for example Embedded C++ which was actually a subset dialect of the C++ language.)

Embedded systems are usually freestanding systems. The gcc-arm-none-eabi compiler is the compiler port for freestanding ARM systems (using ARM's Embedded ABI). It will not come with various OS-specific libs.

When using gcc to compile for freestanding systems you should use the `-ffreestanding` option. This enables the common implementation-defined form of main() and together with `-fno-builtin` it might block various standard library function calls from getting "inlined" into your code. Which we don't want since those libs might not even be present.